# How to adjust the cursor size using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, shell, cursor

We can adjust the cursor size in System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display. How to do this using AppleScript? Maybe `do shell script "...."` or `tell application "System Preferences"`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a script that i used in pre Catalina which no longer worked unfortunately i can't seem to find the original version, but now that i fixed it for the new layout of System Preferences i can share the updated version:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Seeing_Cursor" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    delay 0.2
    
    tell application "System Events"
        set contentView to tab group 1 of group 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
        set theSlider to slider "Cursor size:" of contentView
        
        set stash to value of theSlider
        if value of theSlider is 1.0 then
            set value of theSlider to 4.0
            say "Big Mouse" using "Pipe Organ"
        else
            set value of theSlider to 1.0
            say "Tiny Mouse" using "Zarvox"
        end if
        stash
    end tell
end tell
```

please excuse the voice... that is for my own entertainment.
these snippets are great for my custom touchbar buttons

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape/releases. It is an open-source application that allows the customization of cursors for Mac OS X 10.8-10.10. It can import old MightyMouse files or you can create your own "cape". Included on that page is a link to download a remastered version of Max Rudberg's Svanslös cursors.

And if problem is that it is difficult for you to spot cursor on terminal screen then
Holding down the alt key on Mac OSX changes the cursor to a black cross that has a white border which makes it far easier to spot than the default text bar.

Good luck!